# Is there a Moreh Nevuchim dictionary?

Tags: product-recommendation, rambam

I'm wondering if there exists a dictionary for the more technical terms used in the Moreh Nevuchim? (Any of the translations).
I know I could just use an English translation and match up the words, but a dictionary would be more useful.

Comment: Seems contradictory - if a dictionary explained the "Guide to the perplexed" you wouldn't be perplexed anymore, would you? :-) :-)

Comment: @DanF Unless the dictionary does a bad job!

Comment: If you're learning M"N in Hebrew, how are you not using a translation?

Comment: I would advise not using pain English translation of technical terms. If you don't have a familiarity with peripatetic philosophy before starting the guide, you're going to struggle.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a book dedicated to that:

[*Philosophical Terms in the Moreh Nebukim*](https://books.google.ca/books/about/Philosophical_terms_in_the_Moreh_nebukim.html?id=WRpIAAAAMAAJ), by Israel Efros.

Also, appended to the end of standard editions of ibn Tibbon's translation is ibn Tibbon's *Peirush ha-Milim ha-Zarot*, which is a glossary of philosophical terms.

Answer (score 0):

[Sefer Ruach Chen.](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/34994) is an introductory book  meyuchas to Rabbi Yehuda Ibn Tibbon. A very valuable tool.